# Shortcut for using eyedropper tool to select color from artwork to change text - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, creative-cloud, eyedropper

Was wondering if there was a faster way to change the colour of text using the eye dropper tool to sample colour from some artwork. At the moment I have to click out of the text tool, use the selection tool to select the text and then select the eye dropper tool to recolour the text. Ideally I would like a shortcut to use for the eye dropper tool so that I don't have to exit out of the text tool.

Comment: When typing text, you can change the color in the fly between hitting 2 letter keys. The eyedropper can be ON all the time during the typing. Only learn to decide the color of a letter before typing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the cursor is blinking, indicating editing mode, in a live text string...

- <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit text editing, the text *object* will remain selected.
- Then tap <kbd>i</kbd> to select the Eyedropper Tool